# Reference to a formula with inputbox method

Tags: vba, excel, date

I wanted to apply a `Text(E2,"MM/DD/YYYY")` formula via excel VBA. I use multiple sheets, Cell destination and the Cell reference is not fixed. Hence i used Input-box method to for Cell destination which is working perfect, and wanted to manually select or change cell reference in the formula via inputbox method.
E.g. if i write above formula in A2 cell and my target cell is E2. Cell selection should happen via inputbox.

Initially my plan was to select both the things with inputbox, but i am just a beginner and did not managed to do that hence changed the plan and re-written the code. But the codes seems to be having some issues while editing formula range in inputbox, sometimes it doesn't consider my iputs. If i Say Text`(E2,"MM/DD/YYYY")` then it selects Text(D2 or something,"MM/DD/YYYY")

```
Option Explicit

Sub FinalTxtDte()

Dim Rng As range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Frmla As String
Dim DestRng As range

On Error Resume Next ' if the user presses "Cancel"

Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Select a Cell which needs to be converted in Date format.", "Range Selection", Type:=8)

Err.Clear

On Error GoTo 0

If Not Rng Is Nothing Then

    Frmla = "=TEXT(" & Rng.Address("False", "False") & ",""MM/DD/YYYY"")"

    On Error Resume Next ' if the user presses "Cancel"

    Set DestRng = Application.InputBox("Select a Cell where you would like to get a Converted Date.", "Range Selection", Type:=8)

    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not DestRng Is Nothing Then

        DestRng.Formula = Frmla

    LastRow = Rng.End(xlDown).Row
    DestRng.Select
    range(Selection, Selection.Offset(LastRow - Rng.Row, 0)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    range(Selection, Selection.Offset(LastRow - Rng.Row, 0)).Value _
    = range(Selection, Selection.Offset(LastRow - Rng.Row, 0)).Value

    End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `r[0]c[1]` will offset the selection by 1. Use `r[0]c[0]`

Comment: Comment out the On Error line and see what happens. I think you should probably check whether Rng Is Nothing rather than ="".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will let you use 2 `InputBox`es to select the cell and the formula target (currently according to your post requaet it's for 1 Cell).

I've modifed the 2nd `InputBox` to select the destination range for the formula.

You need to keep the `On Error Resume Next` (and later the `On Error GoTo 0`) in case the user selects the `"Cancel"` option in the InputBox.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TextDateFormula()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Frmla As String, Txt As String
Dim DestRng As Range

On Error Resume Next ' if the user presses "Cancel"
Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Select a cell.", "Range Selection", Type:=8)
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

If Not Rng Is Nothing Then    
    Frmla = "=TEXT(" & Rng.Address(True, True) & ",""MM/DD/YYYY"")"

    On Error Resume Next ' if the user presses "Cancel"
    Set DestRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range to add Decimal Hours.", "Range Selection", Type:=8)
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not DestRng Is Nothing Then
        DestRng.Formula = Frmla
    End If        
End If

End Sub
```

---

**Edit 1**: In order for the formula not to take the absolute address, modify the code line below:

```
Frmla = "=TEXT(" & rng.Address(False, False) & ",""MM/DD/YYYY"")"
```

You need to modify the section inside the brackets after the `Address("Row Absolute", "Column Absolute")` , so modify column and row setting according to your needs.

Comment: thanks for helping. I have added few more actions in your code and modified the original post, i wanted you to please check it. The action is copying, down the formula with fixed reference. i am getting wrong output. Let me know if you have any questions for this.

Comment: OK, so the code is working fine besides the absolute refference ? you want the relative referance so you can drag down ?

Comment: for draggin it down i have added few lines in the coded, so macro should do it automatically.

Comment: @Rosh see my answer and code sample on how to address your request (under **Edit 1**)

Comment: @Rosh so? any feedbacks ? is it working now like you intended ?

Comment: Thanks Man! i accepted the answer, the code is working find. I made some changes and Update the Code in my Questions. Thank you So much.